# Comparing prolog lists

Tags: prolog, list

I'm trying to make a prolog predicate "comprueba(A,B,C,D,E)" that do the next statements:

- All arguments are lists.
- List D contains only the elements that are on A and B at the same time.
- List D elements number of ocurrences must be the same ocurrences in A.
- List E contains only the elements of A that are not on C and not on D.
- List E elements number of ocurrences must be three times the occurrences in A.
- There are no more elements than these in D or E.
- The predicate must be true even if the order of D or E differs from A.

So here is my code:

```
comprueba(A,B,C,D,E) :- lista([A]), 
                        lista([B]), 
                        lista([C]), 
                        lista([D]), 
                        lista([E]),
                        inter(A,B,D),
                        checko(D,D,A,1).
                        %checke2(A,C,D,E),
                        %checko(E,E,A,3).

lista([]).
lista([_|T]) :-lista(T).

inter([], _, []).
inter([H1|T1], L2, [H1|Res]) :- memberof(H1, L2), inter(T1, L2, Res).
inter([_|T1], L2, Res) :- inter(T1, L2, Res).

checke2([],_,_,_).
checke2(A,C,D,E) :- subtract(A,D,X), subtract(A,C,Y), inter(X,Y,E).

count(_, [], N) :- N is 0. 
count(X, [X|T], N1) :- count(X, T, N2), N1 is N2 + 1.     
count(X, [Y|T], N) :- X \= Y, count(X, T, N).  

memberof(X, [X|_]).
memberof(X, [_|T]) :- memberof(X,T).

checko([],_,_,_).
checko([H|T],L1,L2,N) :- count(H,L1,N1), count(H,L2,N2), N3 is N * N2, N1 = N3, checko(T,L1,L2,N).
```

After doing some testing I'm stucked, because I cannot get it true, if the list are not on the same order, e.g:

```
17 ?- comprueba([1,2,3,4,2,5,8,9],[2,3,4,7],[1,2,3,8],[2,2,3,4],[5,5,5,9,9,9]).
false.

18 ?- comprueba([1,2,3,4,2,5,8,9],[2,3,4,7],[1,2,3,8],[2,3,4,2],[5,5,5,9,9,9]).
true
```

So I really ask you for help to try to solve it, and continue with the next part, with E list.

Thanks you in advance.

PD:
sorry if the format is not the properly, it's my first post here :)

Comment: What restrictions do you have on what available predicates you can use? SWI prolog has a number of predicates available that manipulate lists as sets, so just about every operation you are wanting to do here is a call to one of these set predicates. If you just are dealing with an ordering issue, you could `msort` your lists first before operating on them.

Comment: I should not use comparing lists predicates, only if I make them... I only used subtract, but I will do by my own later. Ok, I will try to order it before, I will tell you what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a goal that describes D as any permutation of the 4th list (in the below example D2).

```
comprueba(A,B,C,D,E) :- lista([A]), 
                        lista([B]), 
                        lista([C]), 
                        lista([D2]), 
                        lista([E]),
                        inter(A,B,D2),
                        checko(D2,D2,A,1),
                        permutation(D2,D).
```

If you are not allowed to use permutation/2 from library(lists) permutation could look something like this:

```
% permutation(List1,List2)
% List2 is a permutation of List1
permutation([],[]).
permutation(Xs,[Z|Zs]) :-
    element(Z,Xs,Ys),
    permutation(Ys,Zs).

% element(X,List1,List2)
% X is element of List1, List2 = List1 without X
element(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
element(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|Zs]) :-
    element(X,Ys,Zs).
```

With this additional goal your predicate comprueba/5 works with both of your queries.

```
?- comprueba([1,2,3,4,2,5,8,9],[2,3,4,7],[1,2,3,8],[2,2,3,4],[5,5,5,9,9,9]).
yes
?- comprueba([1,2,3,4,2,5,8,9],[2,3,4,7],[1,2,3,8],[2,3,4,2],[5,5,5,9,9,9]).
yes
```

Comment: Yes, it was my problem, I forgot to permutate it :). Ok, now is working, and also could finish the predicate. Thanks you